# How to configure multiple batches in one module

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron, spring-batch, jobs

I have a module which consists of multiple batch modules. And I have to run them at ones. Each of this batch modules has it's own data source.
Here is the high level view:

```
-- batch-module
   -- batch-server
   -- batch-one (I changed names)
   -- batch-two
   -- batch-three
```

I put persistence, batch configs and configurers inside batch-server.
From whitelabel I'm running batch-server.
And here is the problem. Batch metadata tables are getting created only for one datasource which I annotated as @Primary. But even though, they are not getting filled after job execution.
I'm putting samples(I changed names and packages):

For batch-one(but it's inside batch-server)

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.test.common", entityManagerFactoryRef = "commonEntityManager", transactionManagerRef = "commonTransactionManager")
public class PersistenceCommonAutoConfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "commonDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="common-datasource")
    public DataSource commonDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name="commonEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean commonEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder.dataSource(commonDataSource()).packages("com.test.common").build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "commonTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager commonTransactionManager(@Qualifier("commonEntityManager") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(factory.getObject());
    }
}
```

For batch-two:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.test.second", entityManagerFactoryRef = "secondEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "secondTransactionManager")
public class PersistenceSecondAutoConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "secondDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "second-datasource")
    public DataSource secondDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean secondEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder.dataSource(secondDataSource()).packages("com.test.second").build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager secondTransactionManager(@Qualifier("secondEntityManager") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(factory.getObject());
    }
}
```

Here are my batch related configs:

```
@Component
@Import({PersistenceCommonAutoConfiguration.class})
public class CommonBatchConfigurer extends SimpleBatchConfiguration {

    @Qualifier("commonTransactionManager")
    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Bean
    BatchConfigurer configurer(@Qualifier("commonDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DefaultBatchConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void setDataSource(@Qualifier("commonDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
                super.setDataSource(dataSource);
            }

            @Override
            public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
                return transactionManager;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And batch config

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableBatchProcessing
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = CommonBatchConfigurer.class)
public class CommonBatchConfig {

    private final JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    private final Job processExpirationJob;

    @Scheduled(cron = "${spring.batch.scheduler.cron.expiration}")
    public void launchExpirationJob() throws Exception {
        launchJob(processExpirationJob, "Expiration");
    }

    private void launchJob(Job job, String name) throws Exception {
        JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("JobID", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())).toJobParameters();
        JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, param);
        log.info("Job finished with status : {}", execution.getStatus());
    }

}
```

And the same way I configured the others.
Do someone know what I'm doing wrongly?

Comment: `For batch-one(but it's inside batch-server)`: This makes your question confusing. Are you trying to make all jobs write meta-data to the same job repository and put common configuration in `batch-server`? Do your jobs require different datasources (apart from the one backing the job repository)?

Comment: batch-one(but it's inside batch-server): I meant that configurations are inside batch-server. Yeah, each batch requires separate datasource and I'd like to get filled meta-data tables for each datasource.

Comment: I tried several things with my batch configurations. For instance, I removed two batch modules and kept one. After that when I extended `DefaultBatchConfigurer` or implemented `BatchConfigurer` and overrided `getJobRepository, getTransactionManager, getJobLauncher, getJobExplorer` methods batch related metadata-tables were getting filled. 

But when I get back the other two batches and used one of this configurers for thems, the project didn't run and said there should be one `BatchConfigurer`.

Comment: `I'd like to get filled meta-data tables for each datasource`: In this case, define a `JobRepository` per datasource and tell each job which `JobRepository` to use to report its meta-data.

Comment: Alright, thank you, I'll try!